# Cloning encrypted drive

Tags: encryption, backup

I need to clone a Veracrypt encrypted drive before destroying the drive. The clone will be stored on a hard drive with other files. It has to be identical, include all data and able to be decrypted using Veracrypt. What should I use to do that? (Windows operating system)

Answer (score 2):

dd is the best choice for bit for bit copies. While native on Linux this is also available on windows via http://www.chrysocome.net/dd. You will need a way to connect the hard drive to a already running OS to make the copy for best results.

Answer (score 0):

Any cloning product that can do sector-by-sector copy can be used.
You can't use any other copy method except sector-by-sector,
since the cloning program will probably see the disk
as being an unknown disk type that it cannot understand.

Some examples of such Windows products can be found, with reviews, in the article
[Best Free Drive Cloning Software](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm).

The disks have better be of the same size for best results.
If the target is smaller the copy might be invalid, and if larger then the
copied disk might not be totally utilizable.
If the disks are not of the same size, it would be better to decrypt the source,
do the cloning, then re-encrypt both disks.

Comment: No on disks of same size. He wants to archive them to a file, not clone to a disk. This is common practice in forensic shops.

Comment: @user10216038: Most of the products that do sector-by-sector copy can also do that.